# using .eq closest to get upper div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've tried using .closest, .parents and .eq to get this div selected on page load, and can not figure out why it is not working. My HTML is:

```
<div class="top">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div></div>
      <ul class="first"></ul>
      <div></div>
      <ul class="first active">
         <li><a class="current"></a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="first"></ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

So on page load I want the div above 'active' to change colors, but can't get it to work. I've tried:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 if ($('.current').is(':visible')){
    $('.current').closest('div').addClass('active');
 });
```

Comment: which div are you talking about??

Comment: right above 'first active'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect selector to target required div. You need to first traverse to parent ul element and then to its previous sibling div. Like this:

```
$('.current:visible').closest('ul').prev().addClass('active');
```

Comment: yep this works, but why doesn't what I have work? I would think based on the tree it would go directly to the first div?

Comment: That is because closest traverse parent by parent level. Due to which it was targeting div with class top. However your target element is one of the sibling of its parent element.

Comment: @Keith : glad it help

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to select the prev sibling.

```
$('.current:visible').each(function(){
    $(this).closest('ul').prev('div').addClass('active');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($('.current').is(':visible')){
   $('.current').parents('.active').prev('div').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `div` above `.first.active` in the source is a sibling, not a parent, hence why `closest()` doesn't work for you in the method you're using.

You can use `closest()` to get the parent `ul`, then `prev()` to get the `div` you require. Try this:

```
if ($('.current').is(':visible')) {
    $('.current').closest('ul').prev('div').addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.closest` will look up the DOM tree to find the closest matching "parental" element. The div you are trying to get is actually a "sibling" of the `<ul>` so `.closest` won't find it.

So you would need to go up to the `<ul>`, then get the element "previous" to that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 if ($('.current').is(':visible')){
    $('.current').closest('ul').prev('div').addClass('active');
 });
```